# Getting SWT StyledText widget to always scroll to its end

Tags: java, swt, styledtext

How do I get a SWT StyledText widget to always stay scrolled to the end it even as new lines of text gets appended to it?

I tried to look for some functions that could allow me to set the scroll position but I can't find any. There isn't a property that lets me do this either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply add this line, after you've added text:

```
styledText.setTopIndex(styledText.getLineCount() - 1);
```

If you change the content of your StyledText on more than one place, use a listener on `Modify`, to [not repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

```
styledText.addListener(SWT.Modify, new Listener(){
    public void handleEvent(Event e){
        styledText.setTopIndex(styledText.getLineCount() - 1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Another variation:

```
    styledText.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {

        @Override
        public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
            styledText.setTopIndex(styledText.getLineCount() - 1);

        }
    });
```

Comment: I like that solution more, but I would prefer to cast e.widget